# Convert Unsigned Long to an string in ascii

Tags: c#, c++, c

I need to convert an *unsigned long* to a *string* in a base "b" in *ascii*.

I receive the *long*, and the *base* (0 < b < 16), and i need to set it in a buffer.
Any idea how to do that, without itoa()??

Cumps

Comment: Those are three different languages - do you want 3 different answers?

Comment: @DaSilva All of them? Any of them?

Comment: `Any idea how to do that, without itoa()` what is the relation with c# ? Convert.ToString(longVar,2 or 8 or 10 or 16) is enough?

Comment: this is for my college and i need the solution in one of the language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure - it's trivial (sadly, I currently can't compile the code so there are probably a couple of typos):

```
std::string convert(unsigned long value, unsigned long base) {
    std::string rc;
    do {
        rc.push_back("0123456789abcde"[value % base]);
    } while (base - 1? value /= base: value--);
    std::reverse(rc.begin(), rc.end());
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Er, yes - it doesn't work for base 1. What would be expected output for base 1? A sequence of `0`? With 0 being `0` and 1 being `00` - this would be, at least easily achieved (adjusted the code). BTW, you test case is flawed at the other end.

Comment: I always saw a series of N zeros as base one for the value N, and keep forgetting that it's cheating and not standard.  I wouldn't be even remotely surprised if my test has flaws, but at least I showed your concept compiles and runs.

Comment: Well, you correctly pointed out that base 1 didn't work but base 16 wasn't asked for ;) I don't know what the standard is for base 1 representation, though. The code above print `N + 1` zeros for `N`.

Comment: Dietmar: There is a standard for base 1 representation, but it's cheating.  Mathematically it can't actually be done, and it doesn't remotely follow the same pattern.  So that's fine either way.  I didn't actually validate the results, I merely intended to validate the process :P

Answer (score 2):

This is pseudo code please forgive me for any syntax errors:

```
char  rem  = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'}
int   base = 6;
int   len  = 6;
int   rm   = 0;
int   cur  = 0;
char *res  = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len + 1);

unsigned long num  = 123456;

while(num != 0) {
    rm         = num % base;
    res[cur++] = rem[rm]
    num        = num / base;
}

res[cur] = '\0';
```

Something like this should do the trick.

Comment: Won't that string be backwards?

Comment: Yes, I guess you will need to add a reverse call to the res string... sorry it's 2:30AM here... :)